# what does this how mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> Then she changed her desk into a pig and back again. They were all very impressed and couldn't wait to get started, but soon realized they weren't going to be changing the fur-niture into animals for a long time. After taking a lot of complicated notes, they were each given a match and started trying to turn it into a needle. By the end of the lesson, only Hermione Granger had made any difference to her match; Professor McGonagall showed the class **how it had gone all silver and pointy** and gave Hermione a rare smile.
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

I guess *how* is an intensifier in the sentence (OALD [#5](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/how); similar to [what #3](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/what)). So the sentence would mean McGonagall showed the class Hermione’s match had gone all silver and pointy really fantastic. Is this right or do I have see other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definition 1 in the dictionary you link to, "in what way or manner".  You can replace it with *that* and the sentence will be approximately the same:

> Professor McGonagall showed the class **that** it had gone all silver and pointy

The uses of *how* and *what* you describe (OALD *how* #5 and *what* #3) can't appear in this position.  They appear in exclamative phrases.